# Incremental Deployment Azure ARM Templates

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I Am deploying resources via ARM Template inside VSTS Release Definition.

For Example, I have Azure function App which is deployed and after the deployment, I add some keys in the Application Settings via portal.

During the next deployment , as this function app is inside ARM template, the Application settings are removed.

How can I ignore the resource if it exists, and only create it via ARM template if it doesnt exist in the Resource Group.

I am using New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment  in the ps file.

Comment: Do you have an app setting section in your ARM template ???

Comment: Can you post a relevant sample of your ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify -Mode when usng New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment, the deployment itself is incremental by default. The deployment looks through your resource group and does not touch resources that are configured exactly as they are in the template.

That being said, if some parts of your function app are not in the template (such as app settings), they will be "rewritten" once you rerun the deployment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy

Comment: This is not 100% accurate across all Azure resources. It truly depends what you have changed in the portal. For instance if adding a Network restriction to say a KeyVault manually in the portal and you redeploy your Key Vault w/o that restriction the end result will be the Network restriction will remain. Technically the ARM template didn't define anything about restrictions, thus your ARM didn't evaluate the delta between the two.

In this case, the AppSettings section in this App Service ARM template and thus it is doing a delta between what is defined in the portal and via the template.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I posted a similar question before. If you set additional app settings via Azure CLI or the portal, and the ARM template contains app settings as well, it will set only the app settings defined via the ARM template.

[Azure Function+ARM: merge app settings with current settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063731/azure-functionarm-merge-app-settings-with-current-settings)

My current workaround is to read the current app settings from the webapp and merge them with my "default settings".

Some code for that:

```
$appSettings = @{ }

$functionAppExists = Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name $AppName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($functionAppExists) {
    $appSettingsObject = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$AppName/appsettings" -Action list -Force
    $appSettingsObject.properties.psobject.properties | Foreach-Object { $appSettings[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
}
$appSettings["FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION"] = "~$FunctionAppVersion"
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName)[0].Value
$appSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"] = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$StorageAccountName;AccountKey=$storageAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

```
  "parameters": {
    "appSettings": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION":"~2"
      }
    }
  }

  {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "appsettings",
      "type": "config",
      "condition": "[not(empty(parameters('appSettings')))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": "[parameters('appSettings')]"
    }
```